# ¿Sera posible transformar mi latitude y longitude a un zip code usa?

Tags: ionic

Sera posible obtener el zip code usa con mis latitude y longitude?
Estoy utilizando ionic 2 y el plugin de cordova-geolocation. Ya obtengo la latitude y longitude. 
Pregunto esto porque tengo un form el cual solicito el zip code, pero seria mejor si se obtuviera automáticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible, puedes validarlo con : [All US zip codes](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666)

deberas leer el archivo y buscar lat/lon por aproximación